# how to overlay a polygon over SpatialPointsDataFrame and preserving the SPDF data?

Tags: r, overlay

I have a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with some additional data. I would like to extract those points inside a polygon and at the same time, preserve `SPDF` object and its corresponding data.

So far I've had little luck and resorted to matching and merging through a common ID, but this works only becaues I have gridded data with individual IDS.

Here's a quick example, I'm looking for points inside the red square.

```
library(sp)
set.seed(357)
pts <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), var1 = runif(100), var2 = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE))
coordinates(pts) <- ~ x + y
class(pts)
plot(pts)
axis(1); axis(2)

ply <- matrix(c(-1,-1, 1,-1, 1,1, -1,1, -1,-1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
ply <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(ply)), ID = 1)))
ply <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr = ply, data = data.frame(polyvar = 357))
plot(ply, add = TRUE, border = "red")
```

The most obvious approach would be to use `over`, but this returns the data from the polygon.

```
> over(pts, ply)
    polyvar
1        NA
2       357
3       357
4        NA
5       357
6       357
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a reproducible example. Always helps when trying to understand a problem!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the `sp::over` help:

```
 x = "SpatialPoints", y = "SpatialPolygons" returns a numeric
      vector of length equal to the number of points; the number is
      the index (number) of the polygon of ‘y’ in which a point
      falls; NA denotes the point does not fall in a polygon; if a
      point falls in multiple polygons, the last polygon is
      recorded.
```

So if you convert your `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to `SpatialPolygons` you get back a vector of indexes and you can subset your points on `NA`:

```
> over(pts,as(ply,"SpatialPolygons"))
  [1] NA  1  1 NA  1  1 NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  1 NA  1 NA
 [26]  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA  1  1
 [51]  1 NA NA NA  1 NA  1 NA  1 NA NA  1 NA  1  1 NA  1  1 NA  1 NA  1  1  1  1
 [76]  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  1 NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1 NA

> nrow(pts)
[1] 100
> pts = pts[!is.na(over(pts,as(ply,"SpatialPolygons"))),]
> nrow(pts)
[1] 54
> head(pts@data)
         var1 var2
2  0.04001092    v
3  0.58108350    v
5  0.85682609    q
6  0.13683264    y
9  0.13968804    m
10 0.97144627    o
>
```

For the doubters, here's evidence that the conversion overhead is not a problem:

Two functions - first Jeffrey Evans' method, then my original, then my hacked conversion, then a version based on `gIntersects` based on Josh O'Brien's answer:

```
evans <- function(pts,ply){
  prid <- over(pts,ply)
  ptid <- na.omit(prid) 
  pt.poly <- pts[as.numeric(as.character(row.names(ptid))),]
  return(pt.poly)
}

rowlings <- function(pts,ply){
  return(pts[!is.na(over(pts,as(ply,"SpatialPolygons"))),])
}

rowlings2 <- function(pts,ply){
  class(ply) <- "SpatialPolygons"
  return(pts[!is.na(over(pts,ply)),])
}

obrien <- function(pts,ply){
pts[apply(gIntersects(columbus,pts,byid=TRUE),1,sum)==1,]
}
```

Now for a real-world example, I've scattered some random points over the `columbus` data set:

```
require(spdep)
example(columbus)
pts=data.frame(
    x=runif(100,5,12),
    y=runif(100,10,15),
    z=sample(letters,100,TRUE))
coordinates(pts)=~x+y
```

Looks good

```
plot(columbus)
points(pts)
```

Check the functions are doing the same thing:

```
> identical(evans(pts,columbus),rowlings(pts,columbus))
[1] TRUE
```

And run 500 times for benchmarking:

```
> system.time({for(i in 1:500){evans(pts,columbus)}})
   user  system elapsed 
  7.661   0.600   8.474 
> system.time({for(i in 1:500){rowlings(pts,columbus)}})
   user  system elapsed 
  6.528   0.284   6.933 
> system.time({for(i in 1:500){rowlings2(pts,columbus)}})
   user  system elapsed 
  5.952   0.600   7.222 
> system.time({for(i in 1:500){obrien(pts,columbus)}})
  user  system elapsed 
  4.752   0.004   4.781
```

As per my intuition, its not a great overhead, in fact it might be less of an overhead than converting all the row indexes to character and back, or running na.omit to get missing values. Which incidentally leads to another failure mode of the `evans` function...

If a row of the polygons data frame is all `NA` (which is perfectly valid), then the overlay with `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` for points in that polygon will produce an output data frame with all `NA`s, which `evans()` will then drop:

```
> columbus@data[1,]=rep(NA,20)
> columbus@data[5,]=rep(NA,20)
> columbus@data[17,]=rep(NA,20)
> columbus@data[15,]=rep(NA,20)
> set.seed(123)
> pts=data.frame(x=runif(100,5,12),y=runif(100,10,15),z=sample(letters,100,TRUE))
> coordinates(pts)=~x+y
> identical(evans(pts,columbus),rowlings(pts,columbus))
[1] FALSE
> dim(evans(pts,columbus))
[1] 27  1
> dim(rowlings(pts,columbus))
[1] 28  1
>
```

BUT `gIntersects` is faster, even with having to sweep the matrix to check intersections in R rather than in C code. I suspect its the `prepared geometry` skills of GEOS, creating spatial indexes - yeah, with `prepared=FALSE` it takes a bit longer, about 5.5 seconds.

I'm surprised there isn't a function to either straight return the indices or the points. When I wrote `splancs` 20 years ago the point-in-polygon functions had both...

Comment: Great, this also works for multiple polygons (I've added an example to play with into Joshua's answer).

Comment: With large polygon datasets coercion into a SpatialPolygons object is a lot of overhead and not necessary. Applying "over" to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame returns the row index which can be used to subset the points. See my example below.

Comment: A *lot* of overhead? Its essentially just taking the @polygons slot from the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object. You can even 'fake' it by reassigning the class of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to be "SpatialPolygons" (although this is hacky and not recommended). Anything that is going to use the geometry is going to have to get that slot at some stage anyway, so relatively speaking its no overhead at all. Its insignificant anyway in any real-world application where you are then going to be doing a load of point-polygon tests.

Comment: There is more than speed considerations in accounting for overhead. In creating a new object in the R namespace you are using necessary RAM. Where this is not a problem in a small datasets it will effect performance with large data. R does exhibit a linear performance die off. As the data gets larger performance takes a ding. If you do not need to create an additional object why would you?

Comment: Good point about NA's in the polygon dataframe. However, you can utilize match or which to return an "honest" vector representing row indexes without worrying about NA's in the polygon dataframe. Besides, as we are arguing over this everybody is ignoring that that most efficient solution proposed was using rgeos and gIntersects.

Comment: We didn't know that until I tested it just now.

Comment: @Spacedman    how can one use this answer on many polygons? That is `pp` should have a column named `ID` which indicates in which polygon the points are located.

Answer (score 13):

`sp` provides a shorter form to select features based on spatial intersection, following the OP example:

```
pts[ply,]
```

as of:

```
points(pts[ply,], col = 'red')
```

Behind the scenes this is short for

```
pts[!is.na(over(pts, geometry(ply))),]
```

The thing to note is that there is a `geometry` method that drops attributes: `over` changes behaviour if its second argument has attributes or not (this was OP's confusion). This works accross all Spatial* classes in `sp`, although some `over` methods require `rgeos`, see [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf) vignette for details, e.g. the case of multiple matches for overlapping polygons.

Comment: Good to know! I was not aware of the geometry method.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Edzer--it's nice to see you here!

Comment: Thanks Bill -- it's getting more quiet on https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/ , or maybe we should develop software that causes more trouble! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You were on the right track with over. The rownames of the returned object correspond to the row index of the points. You can implement your exact approach with just a few addition lines of code.

```
library(sp)
set.seed(357)

pts <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), var1=runif(100), 
                  var2=sample(letters, 100, replace=TRUE))
  coordinates(pts) <- ~ x + y

ply <- matrix(c(-1,-1, 1,-1, 1,1, -1,1, -1,-1), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
  ply <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(ply)), ID=1)))
    ply <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr=ply, data=data.frame(polyvar=357))

# Subset points intersecting polygon
prid <- over(pts,ply)
  ptid <- na.omit(prid) 
    pt.poly <- pts[as.numeric(as.character(row.names(ptid))),]  

plot(pts)
  axis(1); axis(2)
    plot(ply, add=TRUE, border="red")
      plot(pt.poly,pch=19,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Wrong - the rownames of the returned object corresponds to the row index _in_this_case_ - in general the row names seem to be the row names of the points - which might not even be numeric. You could modify your solution to do a character match which might make it a bit more robust.

Comment: @Sapcedman, Don't be so dogmatic. The solution is not incorrect. If you want to subset points to a set of polygons or assign polygon values to points the over function works without coercion. There are multiple was to perform the crosswalk once you have the resulting over object. You solution of coercing to a SpatialPolygon object creates considerable necessary overhead because this operation can be performed directly on the SpatialPolygonDataFrame object. By the way before you edit a post be sure that you are right. The term library and package are used interchangeably in R.

Comment: I've added some benchmarks to my post, and spotted another problem with your function. Also "Packages are collections of R functions, data, and compiled code in a well-defined format. The directory where packages are stored is called the library"

Comment: While you are technically correct regarding "package" vs. "library" your are arguing semantics. I just had an Ecological Modelling editor request that we change our use of "package" (which is actually my preference) to "library". My point is that they are becoming interchangeable terms and a matter of preference.

Comment: "technically correct" as Dr Sheldon Cooper once remarked, "is the best sort of correct". That editor is technically wrong, which is the worst sort of wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible approach using the `rgeos` package. Basically, it makes use of the `gIntersection` function that allows you to intersect two `sp` objects. By extracting the IDs of those points that lie within the polygon, you are afterwards able to subset your original `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, keeping all the corresponding data. The code is almost self-explaining, but if there are any questions, please feel free to ask!

```
# Required package
library(rgeos)

# Intersect polygons and points, keeping point IDs
pts.intersect <- gIntersection(ply, pts, byid = TRUE)

# Extract point IDs from intersected data
pts.intersect.strsplit <- strsplit(dimnames(pts.intersect@coords)[[1]], " ")
pts.intersect.id <- as.numeric(sapply(pts.intersect.strsplit, "[[", 2))

# Subset original SpatialPointsDataFrame by extracted point IDs
pts.extract <- pts[pts.intersect.id, ]

head(coordinates(pts.extract))
              x          y
[1,] -0.5832050 -0.8777367
[2,]  0.3947471  0.7020481
[3,]  0.7667997 -0.9465043
[4,]  0.3174604  0.6416281
[5,] -0.4690151  0.4413502
[6,]  0.4765213  0.6068021

head(pts.extract)
         var1 var2
2  0.04001092    v
3  0.58108350    v
5  0.85682609    q
6  0.13683264    y
9  0.13968804    m
10 0.97144627    o
```

Comment: Should `tmp` be `pts.intersect`? Also, parsing the returned dimnames like that is depending on undocumented behaviour.

Comment: @Spacedman, you're right about `tmp`, forgot to remove it when finishing the code. Also, you're right about parsing the `dimnames`. This was kind of a quick solution to provide the questioner with a fast answer, and there surely are better (and more universal) approaches, for example yours :-)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are after?

One note, on edit: The wrapping call to `apply()` is needed to make this work with arbitrary `SpatialPolygons` objects, possibly containing more than one polygon feature. Thanks to @Spacedman for prodding me to demonstrate how to apply this to the more general case.

```
library(rgeos)
pp <- pts[apply(gIntersects(pts, ply, byid=TRUE), 2, any),]


## Confirm that it works
pp[1:5,]
#              coordinates       var1 var2
# 2 (-0.583205, -0.877737) 0.04001092    v
# 3   (0.394747, 0.702048) 0.58108350    v
# 5    (0.7668, -0.946504) 0.85682609    q
# 6    (0.31746, 0.641628) 0.13683264    y
# 9   (-0.469015, 0.44135) 0.13968804    m

plot(pts)
plot(ply, border="red", add=TRUE)
plot(pp, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Fails horribly if `ply` has more than one feature, because `gIntersects` returns a matrix with one row for each feature. You probably can probably sweep the rows for a TRUE value.

Comment: @Spacedman -- Bingo. Need to do `apply(gIntersects(pts, ply, byid=TRUE), 2, any)`. In fact, I'll go ahead and switch the answer to that, since it encompasses the case of a single polygon as well.

Comment: Ah, `any`. That might be marginally faster than the version I just benchmarked.

Comment: @Spacedman -- From my quick tests, it looks like `obrien` and `rowlings2` run neck and neck, with `obrien` *maybe* 2% faster.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien   how can one use this answer on many polygons? That is `pp` should have a `ID` which indicates in which polygon the points are located.

Comment: @code123 `gIntersects(pts, ply, byid=TRUE)` will record that information, so it's just a matter of extracting it in whatever form you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is an **extremely simple solution** using the `spatialEco` library.

```
library(spatialEco)

# intersect points in polygon
  pts <- point.in.poly(pts, ply)

# check plot
  plot(ply)
  plot(a, add=T)

# convert to data frame, keeping your data
  pts<- as.data.frame(pts)
```

Check the result:

```
pts

>             x          y       var1 var2 polyvar
> 2  -0.5832050 -0.8777367 0.04001092    v     357
> 3   0.3947471  0.7020481 0.58108350    v     357
> 5   0.7667997 -0.9465043 0.85682609    q     357
> 6   0.3174604  0.6416281 0.13683264    y     357
> 9  -0.4690151  0.4413502 0.13968804    m     357
> 10  0.4765213  0.6068021 0.97144627    o     357
```