# Detecting if GPS coordinates fall within polygon of points?

Tags: polygon, point, latitude-longitude, point-in-polygon, point-of-interest

I'm looking for a simple explanation on how to detect if GPS coordinates fall within a polygon of points.

**I would prefer an explanations that can be done using paper and pencil and not programming language specific.**

If I have a list of points (latitude and longitude in degrees) that makes up a polygon. How can I tell if a point falls withing that polygon.

The only data I have access to is the **polygon points** and the **point to check**. An example is: `41.21,-104.77`(point to check) then I have polygon points (`39.39 -101.69 + 48.8335,-106.2435 + 38.803,-109.5781 + 39.4413,-111.043 + 45.6336,-113.7162 + 48.8335,-106.2435`)

[image]

I found a [Java specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287780/detecting-whether-a-gps-coordinate-falls-within-a-polygon-on-a-map) and [an R specific answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133625/checking-if-points-fall-within-polygon-shapefile) but I am looking for a programming language agnostic answer. Something *written in plain English/step by step.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a really simple algorithm how about this:

- Take your point and draw a straight line to the bounding box of your polygon.
- Count how many times it crosses the polygon boundary.
- If number is **odd** it must be **inside**, if **even** it must be **outside**.

Comment: The only data I have access to is the polygon points and the point to check. An example is: `41.21,-104.77`(point to check) then I have polygon points (`39.39 -101.69 + 48.8335,-106.2435 + 38.803,-109.5781 + 39.4413,-111.043 + 45.6336,-113.7162 + 48.8335,-106.2435`) Is there a way to find it with just this info? it seems like the solution above I would need a list of all the points for boundaries... which I do not have. Thanks!

Comment: Awesomely simple implementation of the odd/even rule. Tim, you can only work with the points you have.. those will have to do. find your minimum X and use the Y of the point then imagine a line segment Xmin, Y to X, Y. You can skip any polygon segment not in the range of your points' Y coordinate otherwise for each segment see if the intersection occurs http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/SystemsofLinEq/EMeth.htm the intersection should be in the bounds of the imaginary line and segment or they don't intersect, count the ones that do and if the modulus of that by 2 is 1 you're inside.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I am still a little fuzzy on how to do that. Unfortunately I am not a GIS wiz... Is there a way you could give an answer/example showing a step by step solution on how to do this using the points given in my question? I need to see the process of how someone would do this so I can recreate it. If it helps I am okay with pseudo code, as long as it shows the entire process of how the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: It's high school math, the simultaneous solution of two equations to find the point of intersection *but* the intersection could be out of range which is why you need to constrain.. it should be enough to find the X of the intersection between the minimum X point of the polygon and your GPS X point. First step is to find the equation for both segments (https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html) then solve to find the point that satisfies both. It's been a *very* long time since high school which is why I'd use OGR geometry within method, but perhaps I'm just lazy.