# Identify polygon containing point with R sf package

Tags: shapefile, r, vector, geometry, sf

I would like to be able to map geocoded coordinates to a region on a .shp file in R using the `sf` package.  I can load up the map and plot it but I am struggling with the code to return the region for a geocoded address.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

tt <- read_sf(dsn=path.expand(path), layer = "dhb2015", quiet = TRUE)
#tt <- st_transform(tt, 4326) #Not sure if this step is required with sf?
tt

Simple feature collection with 22 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -177.3579 ymin: -47.72405 xmax: 178.8362 ymax: -33.9585
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 22 x 4
   code  region           Shape_Leng                                                                                geometry
   <chr> <chr>                 <dbl>                                                                     <MULTIPOLYGON [Â°]>
 1 01    Northland           1651929 (((174.2735 -36.28929, 174.2735 -36.28931, 174.2737 -36.28929, 174.2737 -36.28932, 1...
 2 02    Waitemata            927392 (((174.5034 -37.0508, 174.5034 -37.05086, 174.5033 -37.05085, 174.5031 -37.05076, 17...
 3 03    Auckland             778190 (((175.1572 -36.92584, 175.1571 -36.92585, 175.157 -36.92583, 175.1569 -36.92575, 17...
 4 04    Counties Manukau     664223 (((174.9167 -36.87379, 174.9168 -36.87379, 174.9169 -36.87378, 174.9169 -36.8738, 17...
 5 05    Waikato             1498296 (((175.9005 -37.22147, 175.9005 -37.22149, 175.9004 -37.22149, 175.9004 -37.22145, 1...
 6 06    Lakes                623669 (((176.2863 -37.93705, 176.2879 -37.93705, 176.2881 -37.93704, 176.3047 -37.93707, 1...
 7 07    Bay of Plenty        946874 (((176.1953 -37.63174, 176.1952 -37.63187, 176.1951 -37.63188, 176.1949 -37.63185, 1...
 8 08    Tairawhiti           689549 (((178.0497 -38.70606, 178.0497 -38.70606, 178.0498 -38.70604, 178.0499 -38.70588, 1...
 9 09    Taranaki             565796 (((174.0128 -39.06098, 174.0127 -39.06099, 174.0124 -39.06096, 174.0123 -39.06091, 1...
10 10    Hawke's Bay          945440 (((176.989 -39.85827, 176.9889 -39.85829, 176.9887 -39.85827, 176.9886 -39.85821, 17...
# ... with 12 more rows

tt %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = region))
```

[image]

I would like to be able to return the region (polygon) where a point is located.

```
loc=data.frame(
  lon= c(175.278655),
  lat= c(-37.733997),
)
```

I am fairly new to geographic data and would like to make use of the `tidyverse` and `sf` packages if possible.

Comment: Try `sf::st_intersects`

Answer (score 16):

What you are looking can be done using `sf::st_intersects()` as commented. I provide  a full working example using USA states.

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

tt <- read_sf(path, "USA_adm1")

# subset some states to make it plot faster
tt1 <- tt[tt$NAME_1 %in% c("South Dakota", "Wyoming",  
                       "Nebraska", "Iowa"), ]
```

I've added labels over the polygons centroids and now the plot looks like that.

[image: Regions' plot]

Now for the actual work. Assume a `data.frame` of lat-lon values.

```
pnts
           x        y
1 -105.08798 43.27392
2  -99.61295 43.48426
3  -96.22951 43.05443
4  -92.35393 43.04529
5  -96.59861 43.14589
6 -101.45847 42.80751
7 -106.87197 44.22843

pnts$region <- apply(pnts, 1, function(row) {  
   # transformation to palnar is required, since sf library assumes planar projection 
   tt1_pl <- st_transform(tt1, 2163)   
   coords <- as.data.frame(matrix(row, nrow = 1, 
     dimnames = list("", c("x", "y"))))   
   pnt_sf <- st_transform(st_sfc(st_point(row),crs = 4326), 2163)
   # st_intersects with sparse = FALSE returns a logical matrix
   # with rows corresponds to argument 1 (points) and 
   # columns to argument 2 (polygons)

   tt1_pl[which(st_intersects(pnt_sf, tt1_pl, sparse = FALSE)), ]$NAME_1 
})
```

The results are shown below

```
           x        y       region
1 -105.08798 43.27392      Wyoming
2  -99.61295 43.48426 South Dakota
3  -96.22951 43.05443         Iowa
4  -92.35393 43.04529         Iowa
5  -96.59861 43.14589 South Dakota
6 -101.45847 42.80751     Nebraska
7 -106.87197 44.22843      Wyoming
```

and in a plot

[image: plot with points]

EDIT - I add another version for this operation, inspired by a very important comment made by spacedman. This would save some computing time, in particular form datasets with multiple points/polygons or complex geometries.

```
pnts <- data.frame(
"x" = c(-105.08798, -99.61295, -96.22951, 
        -92.35393, -96.59861, -101.45846, -106.87197),
"y" = c(43.27392, 43.48426, 43.05443, 43.04529, 
        43.14589, 42.80751, 44.22843))

# create a points collection
pnts_sf <- do.call("st_sfc",c(lapply(1:nrow(pnts), 
function(i) {st_point(as.numeric(pnts[i, ]))}), list("crs" = 4326))) 

pnts_trans <- st_transform(pnts_sf, 2163) # apply transformation to pnts sf
tt1_trans <- st_transform(tt1, 2163)      # apply transformation to polygons sf

# intersect and extract state name
pnts$region <- apply(st_intersects(tt1_trans, pnts_trans, sparse = FALSE), 2, 
               function(col) { 
                  tt1_trans[which(col), ]$NAME_1
               })
```

Comment: Do the transformations once and then do the intersection wit a single `st_intersection(stpnts, tt1_pl)` rather than slowing things down with apply etc.

Comment: @Spacedman - good point

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly!  What actually happens with the st_transform step?  Is the 2163 a map projection?  How does that work with the crs = 4326?  Thanks for your help, great to get this working!

Comment: @jmc The 2163 map projection is a metric projection for the U.S. whereas for New Zealand you should use another projection. Although it works also with 4326, `st_transform` assumes a metric projection and might cause some errors if a geographic coordinate system is being used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The 2153 projection seems to work well for NZ as far as I can tell.  It appears to be able to discriminate between coordinates very close to region borders correctly.  Do you have any suggestions on how can I find out the most appropriate projection to use for NZ?

Comment: This is a different question. Shortly, Google It - but 2153 seems to be a good one. [see details](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nzgd2000-new-zealand-transverse-mercator-2000/)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of how you can do this, I'm using the significant urban areas shapefile from the Australian Bureau of Statistics.

Firstly this is what my `pnts` variable looks like:

```
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 -34.92 138.62
2 -34.93 138.58
3 -34.95 138.52
4 -27.63 152.71
5 -27.57 153.01
6 -33.9  150.73
7 -33.92 150.99
```

And here is my code:

```
library(sf)
# Shapefile from ABS: 
# https://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.004July%202016?OpenDocument
map = read_sf("data/ABS/shapes/SUA_2016_AUST.shp")

pnts_sf <- st_as_sf(pnts, coords = c('y', 'x'), crs = st_crs(map))

pnts <- pnts_sf %>% mutate(
  intersection = as.integer(st_intersects(geometry, map))
  , area = if_else(is.na(intersection), '', map$SUA_NAME16[intersection])
) 

pnts
```

Output:

```
         geometry intersection area    
*     <POINT [°]>        <int> <chr>   
1 (138.62 -34.92)           79 Adelaide
2 (138.58 -34.93)           79 Adelaide
3 (138.52 -34.95)           79 Adelaide
4 (152.71 -27.63)           60 Brisbane
5 (153.01 -27.57)           60 Brisbane
6  (150.73 -33.9)           31 Sydney  
7 (150.99 -33.92)           31 Sydney
```

FYI those coordinates are locations of weather stations, I used this approach to identify weather stations located in major cities in Australia.

Answer (score 3):

To find the countries of a data.frame with lat-long coordinates, convert them to an sf object with `sf::st_as_sf(mydf, coords=c("lon","lat"), crs=4326)`.
Then intersect it with a map of polygons. This is vectorized, so no loops are needed.
Here's a complete working example:

```r
# Dataframe with latlong coordinates:
d <- read.table(sep=",", header=TRUE, text=
"lat, long
55.685143, 12.580008
52.514464, 13.350137
50.106452, 14.419989
48.847003, 2.337213
51.505364, -0.164752")
dsf <- sf::st_as_sf(d, coords=c("long","lat"), crs=4326)

# Polygons of some countries:
if(!requireNamespace("rworldmap", quietly=TRUE)) install.packages("rworldmap")
map <- rworldmap::getMap()
countries <- c("AUT","BEL","CHE","DEU","DNK","FRA","GBR","CZE","LUX","NLD","POL")
map <- map[map@data$GU_A3 %in% countries, "ADMIN"]
map <- sf::st_as_sf(map)

# Plot for visual reference, uses sf::plot_sf:
plot(map, reset=FALSE)
plot(dsf, add=TRUE, reset=FALSE, pch=16, col="red", cex=1.5)
axis(1, line=-1) ; axis(2, line=-1, las=1)

# Find country of each coordinate:
int <- sf::st_intersects(dsf, map)
int
d$country <- as.character(map$ADMIN[unlist(int)])
d
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to [Michael Gordon's code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/343477/107424) as I found it very useful but confounding until I found the solution.

I also wanted to find if given locations where in a polygon, in my case I was looking at electoral wards in the UK. I substituted my shape file and points but I wasn't getting any intersections, after much searching I started looking at the Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS) for my map and points which is where I would like to add to the code.

```
st_crs(map)
```

This will show the CRS of the map, in my case it produced the following output

```
 Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 27700 
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Although

```
pnts_sf <- st_as_sf(pnts, coords = c('y', 'x'), crs = st_crs(map))
```

sets the map and points to the same CRS I was still not getting any intersections. A bit more googling led me to the fact that there wouldn't be any intersect as the CRS needs to be a Longitude and Latitude projection.

In order to do this after creating the map I added

```
map <- st_transform(map,crs=4326)
```

Now when I run

```
st_crs(map)
```

I get

```
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4326 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

Now I get intersection and appreciate how simple this code is.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution can be achieved by using `st_intersection` instead of `st_intersects`:

```
nc = system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf") %>%
  read_sf()  %>% st_transform(2163) # transform to planar as required by st_intersection()

p = st_sfc(st_point(c(-78.34046, 35.017)) , crs = 4267) %>% 
  st_transform(2163) # transform to  planar as required by st_intersction()

st_intersection(nc, p)$NAME
```

Note: `st_intersection` does work differently than `st_intersects` as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442150/why-use-st-intersection-rather-than-st-intersects.
So this solution might not work in all cases or for large datasets, but for this particular type of question it does.