# Checking if the point lies within the polygon in R using sf package

Tags: r, sf, point-in-polygon

I have a point's coordinates as well as an object with the class of sfc_polygon in R. I would like to check if this point lies inside that polygon or not.

I created an object with the class of sfc_point by applying st_point() function on the point's coordinates and I used the st_intersects function to check what I mentioned above. The code is as follows:

pnts = st_sfc(st_point(c(long,lat)), crs = 3006)
iso = ABC$geom

(lst1 = st_intersects(pnts, iso))
(mat1 = st_intersects(pnts, iso, sparse = FALSE))

## which points fall inside a polygon?

apply(mat1, 1, any)
lengths(lst1) > 0

I plot the polygon and the point and I am sure that the point lies inside the polygon, but the result of the code above is false!

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386503/intersect-points-and-polygons/386504#386504)