# Using 'sp' method to subset SpatialPointsDataFrame with SpatialPolygon returns error in parLapply()

Tags: r, sp, parallel-processing, parallel

I have numerous very large data sets of ship tracking data (Automated Information System; AIS). These are originally in a file geodatabase and can be downloaded [here](https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2014/01/Zone9_2014_01.zip) (this is a smaller file for testing purposes).  After reading in the file using `readOGR`, I subset the data by attributes and then into latitudinal bands like this (warning - file is large and takes a while to download and read in. You will also need ReadFGDB driver support in your version of `rgdal`):

```
  # Libraries
  library(rgdal)
  library(sp)
  library(parallel)

  download.file("https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2014/01/Zone9_2014_01.zip", "temp_file.zip")
  unzip("temp_file.zip", exdir="temp")
  broadcast <- readOGR("temp/Zone9_2014_01.gdb", layer = "Zone9_2014_01_Broadcast")

  # Remove unneeded fields
  broadcast@data <- broadcast@data[,c("SOG", "BaseDateTime", "Status", "VoyageID", "MMSI")]

  # Subset the data
  broadcast <- broadcast[broadcast@data$SOG>0.5,] # remove all points w speed <0.5
  broadcast <- broadcast[broadcast@data$Status==0 | broadcast@data$Status==7 | broadcast@data$Status==8,] # remove all points at anchor

  # Split data set into 4 regions
  coords <- coordinates(broadcast)[,2]

  chnks <- list()
  chnks[[1]] <- broadcast[which(coords<=37),]
  chnks[[2]] <- broadcast[which(coords>37 & coords<=40),]
  chnks[[3]] <- broadcast[which(coords>40 & coords<=44),]
  chnks[[4]] <- broadcast[which(coords>44),]
```

Now `chnks` is a list with four SPtsDFs which I want to clip with a polygon, EEZ.  (EEZ is the US West Coast Exclusive Economic zone).  I'll substitute a simple polygon for EEZ here:

```
EEZ <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(-117, -122, -129, -129, -124, -124, -117),c(32, 30, 39, 47, 49, 39, 32)), hole=F)), "EEZ")))
```

If I use `lapply` to do spatial subset on chnks, it works fine:

```
chunked <- lapply(chnks, FUN = function(x){
# Clip the AIS points to EEZ
return(x[EEZ, ])
})
```

But if I try to use `parLapply`, it fails with an error:

```
  # create cluster
  cluster <- makeCluster(4, outfile = "")
  clusterExport(cl=cluster, varlist = "EEZ")

  chunked <- parLapply(cl = cluster, chnks, fun = function(x){
    # Clip the AIS points to EEZ
    return(x[EEZ, ])
  })
```

> 4 nodes produced errors; first error: object of type 'S4' is not
>   subsettable

It seems like the `sp` method for `[` (which references `points[!is.na(over(points, geometry(polygons))),]` according to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136244/35320) post) is not being loaded to the workers.

Does anyone have an idea how to avoid this error or explicitly export the `sp` method to the parallel clusters?

### Addition

I also tried using `plyr` and `llply()` with `.parallel = T` and got the same failure message.  I would also note that the `sp` package seems to load fine on all of the workers, which I would think should allow the `[` subsetting method for spatial objects.

Comment: Have you tried loading package methods on each of the nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is actually twofold.

- Firstly, and as pointed out by @EdzerPebesma, you are not loading the required packages on each of the 4 nodes separately. You have to use `clusterEvalQ` to tell each node which packages it is going to need to fulfill the required (spatial) tasks.
- Secondly, you need to assign a `proj4string` to the polygon you use for clipping.

Otherwise, you will sooner or later run into

> Error: is(proj4string, "CRS") is not TRUE

even though the parallel cluster is now setup properly. Here is some sample code that should meet your demands.

```
## assign a crs to 'EEZ'
EEZ <- SpatialPolygons(
  list(Polygons(
    list(Polygon(cbind(c(-117, -122, -129, -129, -124, -124, -117), 
                       c(32, 30, 39, 47, 49, 39, 32)), hole = FALSE)), "EEZ")), 
  proj4string = CRS(proj4string(broadcast))
)


### parallelization -----

## register parallel backend
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores() - 1)

## load required packages ('rgdal' automatically attaches 'sp')
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(rgdal))

## export required objects
clusterExport(cl, "EEZ")


### perform operation -----

chunked <- parLapply(cl, chnks, function(x) {
  x[EEZ, ]
})

## deregister parallel backend
stopCluster(cl)
```

@TimSalabim once wrote a nice tutorial about [reading raster data in parallel](https://metvurst.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/reading-raster-data-using-libraryparallel-6/). It comes very close to the above code snippet, so maybe you want to have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks @fdetsch!  That was very helpful.  I am doing this work on Ubuntu and had missed that I needed to use `clusterEvalQ()` in conjunction with `parLapply()` to load packages.  It still seems odd that `sp` looked to be loading on the workers, but not the methods functionality.  Is that because the `sp` methods are stored in package `methods` as @Edzer Pebesma mentioned in the comment above, not in `sp`?

Comment: Also, do I need to export `chnks` to the workers even though it is the list being passed to `parLapply`?  It would seem counterproductive to have to send the whole list object to all workers when they only need the element they will process.

Comment: I confirmed that I do not need to export `chnks` since it is passed to `parLapply`.  Doing so only takes up memory on the workers unnecessarily.  The solution to my issue was explicitly loading the package `rgdal` (and dependency `sp`) to the workers with `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(rgdal))`.  Thanks!

Comment: A classic win-win situation. I didn't know that exporting `chnks` is not necessary, thanks for that!